# Ubuntu not detecting the external display anymore

Tags: hdmi, xrandr, external-monitor

I just installed some updates and restarted and after this then Ubuntu doesn't detect the external display. It's connected with HDMI. What can I do about it? It doesn't appear in display settings. I use a laptop and the builtin display is working and detected, but the external display quit workin after today's update. The computer is a Dell Latitude E7450.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
```

[image]

```
~$ dmesg | grep -E 'VGA|HDMI'
[    0.882972] fb0: VESA VGA frame buffer device
[    5.718803] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from VESA VGA
[    5.719040] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[    6.224466] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input16
[    6.224530] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input17
[    6.224590] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input18



$ dmesg | grep -iE 'fail|error|skip'
[    0.000022] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 5187.65 BogoMIPS (lpj=10375316)
[    3.285636] psmouse serio1: Failed to enable mouse on isa0060/serio1
[    4.077454] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    5.849972] init: failsafe main process (612) killed by TERM signal
[    7.787412] systemd-logind[854]: Failed to start unit user@123.service: Unknown unit: user@123.service
[    7.787417] systemd-logind[854]: Failed to start user service: Unknown unit: user@123.service
[    8.418720] systemd-logind[854]: Failed to start unit user@125.service: Unknown unit: user@125.service
[    8.418725] systemd-logind[854]: Failed to start user service: Unknown unit: user@125.service
[    9.170491] vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   16.373837] systemd-logind[854]: Failed to start unit user@1000.service: Unknown unit: user@1000.service
[   16.373842] systemd-logind[854]: Failed to start user service: Unknown unit: user@1000.service

$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     48.0  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

### Update

The following procedure solved the problem: Boot Ubuntu 14 live from a usb stick. Then reboot to the native installed Ubuntu and the external screen works.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28904/discussion-on-question-by-programmer-400-ubuntu-not-detecting-the-external-displ).

Comment: I think you better post that update as answer at least it solve your problem. Even it seems a workaround (This bug looks hard to reproduce), Ask Ubuntu style is Q&A . It will be highlighted as solved for other users.